# Importing cell as a number from Excel to Python3

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm new to Excel integration and I'm running into this problem.

When I use `ws.cell(row=x, column=y).value` to get the cell value it returns the function which describes the cell value in Excel.

I want to get the value which is displayed in the Excel spreadsheet into Python to use, not its function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you set the kwarg data_only=True the function return the value.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook("file.xlsx", data_only=True)
sh = wb["Sheet_name"]
print(sh["x10"].value)
```

Says.

Comment: What do you mean by "Says."?

Comment: sorry bad english...